# Ignoring 409 errors with Gradle when publishing

Tags: java, maven, github, gradle, http-status-code-409

I configured Gradle for publishing a plugin to GitHub packages. When running the corresponding task, I get a (legitimate) 409, as I try to push the same artifact twice.
Apparently, there is no way to configure GitHub packages to accept overwrites, so I was wondering whether I could tell Gradle to ignore 409 errors and go on with the next file.

I took a look at the [API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository.html), but could not find anything of use.

Comment: were you able to figure out a way to fix this?

Comment: Nope, i found no good solution yet

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I too wasn't able to figure out a good solution for this. If/when I found something I will let you know.